# Could you help me design an algorithm and prove for this problem please?

Tags: algorithm, greedy, proof

I am trying to find an algorithm for this problem that is given in my homework:

> Assume that you have m jobs and n machines. Each machine i has a
> nondecreasing latency function li : N → R that only depends on the
> number of jobs assigned to machine i. To illustrate, if lj(5) = 7,
> then machine j needs to work 7 units of time if it is assigned (any)
> five of the jobs. Assume that li(0) = 0 for all machines i.
>
> Given a
> set of m jobs, and n machines, where each machine is associated with a
> nondecreasing latency function as described above. You are asked to
> give a O(m · lgn) algorithm that assigns each job to a machine such
> that the makespan(the maximum amount of time any machine executes) is
> minimized. Needless to say, but just in case, you need to prove that
> your algorithm is correct.

I am allowed to get some help so this is not cheating.

I am stuck in where and how to start to find an algorithm for this problem, could you help me please?

Comment: ["Help me get started" questions are not a good fit for StackOverflow.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254933/answering-questions-which-ask-for-effort-guidance-not-spoon-fed-solutions).  Try a different website, ask your instructor, talk to a classmate.

Comment: Usually the first thing to do is 1) figure out what a greedy algorithm looks like 2) whether it always returns optimal solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`O(m · lgn)` is good clue.

How assigning every of `m` jobs can take `O(logn)` time? Apparently machines should be organized in some data structure with said time per operation.

Think about priority queue based on binary heap.